# Unlock hidden messages on Telegram Grous

Tags: telegram, groupchat

Now, in the latest updates in Telegram, there's a feature that let's the admins of a group hide/lock the previous sent content on a group, but now, is a new member wants to be unlocked, the content is permanently blocked for new members, even if the group administrators changed the rules (disabled the option).

So, as a new member on a group (not as an admin) there's some way or bot or some script to see the previous content/messages sent to the group?

Any help will be gladly appreciated